# php array with json

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays

I'm using an angularJS controller like this

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.element = function(num){
        var element_id = num;//num;  
        $http.get("customers.php",{params:{"id":element_id}}).then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }
        ,function errorCallback(response){
            $scope.e=response.statustext;
            console.log(e);

        });

    };

});
```

And this is my php arrays

```
 $id = $_GET[id];
    $customer_array = array();

    $customer1 = array(
        'name' => 'LoneStar',
        'city' => 'Houston'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer1;

    $customer2 = array(
        'name' => 'SNHU',
        'city' => 'Manchester'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer2;

    $customer3 = array(
        'name' => "Regis",
        'city' => "Boulder"
    );
```

for customer 1 array how can I just return the city name of just that one element.

Comment: why are you using many arrays instead use a single array and try applying filter condition and return that object alone

Comment: echo json_encode($customer_array); and get the response

Comment: echo $customer_array[0]['city'];

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done with php's `json_encode()` function.

```
$id = $_GET[id];// Assuming this is the customer's name. If not???
$customer_array = array();

$customer1 = array(
    'name' => 'LoneStar',
    'city' => 'Houston'
);

$customer_array[] = $customer1;

$customer2 = array(
    'name' => 'SNHU',
    'city' => 'Manchester'
);

$customer_array[] = $customer2;

$customer3 = array(
    'name' => "Regis",
    'city' => "Boulder"
);
$customer_rquired = array();
// Traverse the array to find the customer data
foreach($customer_array as $key=>$customer_instance){
    if($customer_instance["name"] === $id){
        $customer_required["customer"] = $customer_instance;
        echo json_encode($customer_required);
        break;
    }
}
//What you'd do if no customer is found?
```

This echoed could be accessed in your AngularJS script with `response.data`. There, you'll have a JSON object, that contains the customer instance. 
However IMHO, your data structure to store customer information is not very good. What if there are two customers with the **same name**??

Answer (score 0):

If `$id` contains the INDEX of element in the `customer_array`,it will be like

```
header("Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_decode($customer_array[$id]["city"]);
```

If `$id` contains the NAME element in the `customer_array`,it will be like

```
$customer = array();
$response = array();

foreach ($customer_array as $customer_element) {
    if ($id == $customer_element["name"]) {
        $customer = $customer_element;
    }
}
if (count($customer)) {
    $response = array("city" => $customer["city"]);
}else{
    $response = array("error" => "element not found")
}


header("Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $id = $_GET[id];    // $id = 0 to get the value from the first array   
    $customer_array = array();

    $customer1 = array(
        'name' => 'LoneStar',
        'city' => 'Houston'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer1;

    $customer2 = array(
        'name' => 'SNHU',
        'city' => 'Manchester'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer2;

    $customer3 = array(
        'name' => "Regis",
        'city' => "Boulder"
    );

    echo $customer_array[$id]['city']; //the city value of the first array
```

Answer (score 0):

"for customer 1 array **how can I just return the city name of just that one element**"

Your code:

```
 $customer_array = array();

    $customer1 = array(
        'name' => 'LoneStar',
        'city' => 'Houston'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer1;

    $customer2 = array(
        'name' => 'SNHU',
        'city' => 'Manchester'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer2;

    $customer3 = array(
        'name' => "Regis",
        'city' => "Boulder"
    );
```

Above code makes $`customer_array` exists of three customers:

```
 $customer_array = array(
     array( //First item in array $customer_array
        'name' => 'LoneStar',
        'city' => 'Houston'
     ),
     array( //Second item in array $customer_array
        'name' => 'SNHU',
        'city' => 'Manchester'
     ),
     array( //Third item in array $customer_array
        'name' => "Regis",
        'city' => "Boulder"
    )
 );
```

If not defined keys for an array start at 0 and counts upwards, eg. 0,1,2.3...
For this reason `$customer_array[0]` contains the array:

```
array( //First item in array $customer_array
            'name' => 'LoneStar',
            'city' => 'Houston'
         )
```

`$customers_array[1]` contains the array:

```
array( //Second item in array $customer_array
            'name' => 'SNHU',
            'city' => 'Manchester'
         )
```

and `$customers_array[2]` contains the array:

```
array( //Third item in array $customer_array
        'name' => "Regis",
        'city' => "Boulder"
    )
```

**how can I just return the city name of just that one element?**

Examples:

```
$customers[0]['city'] would return value "Houston"
$customers[1]['city'] would return value "Manchester"
$customers[2]['city'] would return value "Boulder"
```